# in routing of asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a controller called "User" and also is "Index". My action has one parameter.

I want to access this action to type user/id.

I write following

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "user",
    url: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

but not could get any.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: It needs to be `url: "user/{id}"` (and that route definition needs to be before the default route and any other matching routes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample as per your question and is working fine for me.

RouteConfig.cs code:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "user",
            url: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

User Controller Code:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    // GET: User
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Here in this code if i call http://localhost:18218/user/12 I am getting id value as 12 in my ActionResult parameter. can you please check if it meets your requirements.